# Link resultado de casos de teste à apenas um caso de teste

Tags: c#, team-foundation-server, automatização

Olá!
Estou automatizando casos te teste com o Visual Studio e estudando a possibilidade de associar essas automações à casos de teste no TFS.
O problema é que eu consigo associar apenas um caso de teste para a automação, enquanto nossos robôs executam diversos casos de teste.

Algo que tentei é criar um caso de teste "master" e linkar os casos de teste filhos nele, mas o resultado não é herdado pelos outros casos de teste.

Alguém conhece uma maneira de mudar o status de múltiplos casos de teste com apenas uma automação no TFS?
Obrigado!